# No puedo recuperar los datos de Firebase con orderByChild en Android Studio - Solucionado

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

**Problema**

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar ya que llevo el día entero en esto, intento leer datos de Firebase, he hecho ya operaciones de escritura contra la base de datos, pero no puedo acceder a los mismos datos que he registrado, tengo las siguientes reglas en la base de datos:

**Reglas al momento del problema**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "perfiles":{
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"      
    }
  }
}
```

**Optimización de reglas**

La optimización que se dio es aumentar un nivel más de control para garantizar que el usuario logueado tenga acceso únicamente a su nodo de información y no al de otros usuarios (sugerencia de @Franco en sus comentarios).

```
{
  "rules": {
    "perfiles":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Con el problema**

Y el siguiente código en un fragment

```
    baseDatos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    perfilesReferencia = baseDatos.getReference("perfiles");
    vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

    // se obtiene al usuario logueado
    usuarioLogueado = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Query consulta = perfilesReferencia.orderByChild("correo").equalTo(usuarioLogueado.getEmail());
    consulta.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds) {

            Perfil perfilEncontrado = ds.getValue(Perfil.class);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),perfilEncontrado.getCorreo(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            cedulaET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getCedula());
            nombresET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getNombres());
            apellidosET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getApellidos());
            nacimientoET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getNacimiento());
            whatsappET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getWhatsapp());
            direccionET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getDireccion());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha encontrado el perfil",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**Optimización de Código**

Básicamente lo que se mejoró en este código es no preguntar en el query por el correo del usuario logueado sino una modificación al momento de registrar el perfil y no utilizar una clave aleatoria, sino el uid del usuario y en el query trabajar con esta uid (otra sugerencia de @Franco).

```
public void verificaPerfil(View view) {

    Query consulta = perfilesReferencia.child(usuarioLogueado.getUid());

    consulta.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds) {

            if(ds.exists()){
                Perfil perfilEncontrado = ds.getValue(Perfil.class);

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),perfilEncontrado.getCorreo(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                cedulaET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getCedula());
                nombresET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getNombres());
                apellidosET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getApellidos());
                nacimientoET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getNacimiento());
                whatsappET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getWhatsapp());
                direccionET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getDireccion());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Aún no ha ingresado los datos de su perfil",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Ocurrió un error en la ejecución",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return;
}
```

**Estructura con el problema**

La estructura usa en este caso una clave aleatoria obtenida a través de un método de la base de datos:

```
{
  "perfiles" : {
    "-LReGzJ4jtu1pCfHqsGa" : {
      "apellidos" : "Jaramillo",
      "cedula" : "0103780835",
      "correo" : "info@maquinas.com",
      "direccion" : "Salvador Allende",
      "nacimiento" : "5/3/1983",
      "nombres" : "Andres",
      "whatsapp" : "0984228708"
    }
  }
}
```

**Optimización de estructuras**

En este caso el único cambio fue registrar los datos con el uid del usuario logueado, (Una sugerencia más de @Franco).

```
{
  "perfiles" : {
    "-LReGzJ4jtu1pCfHqsGa" : {
      "apellidos" : "Jaramillo",
      "cedula" : "0103780835",
      "correo" : "info@maquinas.com",
      "direccion" : "Salvador Allende",
      "nacimiento" : "5/3/1983",
      "nombres" : "Andres",
      "whatsapp" : "0984228708"
    }
  }
}
```

Hasta aquí optimizaciones que vinieron en favor de un mejor funcionamiento de la aplicación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

El código inclusive sin las optimizaciones se encontraba funcionalmente correcto y no fue la causa para que no se pueda recuperar la información de la base de datos, el problema estuvo en que la clase Perfil, no contemplaba el constructor sin argumentos y solo el constructor con argumentos y esto fue lo que impedía que se haga la recuperación de los datos desde la base de datos.

Comment: la solución no va en tu pregunta, por favor editala y dejala como estaba; si quien te respondió te resolvió el problema entonces calificale la aportación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para recuperar los datos asegurate que los atributos de tu clase Perfil se llamen igual que los nodos en Firebase. Sino quieres usar el mismo nombre tenes que hacer lo siguiente

```
public Class Perfil {

   public Perfil(){} //Firebase requiere que exista un constructor sin argumentos

   //Agregas tantos constructores como necesites

  @PropertyName("cedula") //donde el nombre es el nombre del nodo en firebase
  private String cedula; //aclarando el nombre en la linea de arriba no hace falta
                         //que tengan el mismo nombre que en firebase.

  public void setCedula(String cedula){
     this.cedula = cedula;
  }

  @PropertyName("cedula") //también es necesario aclararlo en el getter
  public String getCedula(){
     return this.cedula;
  }

  //haces lo mismo para cada atributo
}
```

De todas formas te recomiendo que cambies la estructura, cuando agregas un perfil del usuario en vez de crear una entrada con una clave aleatoria usa como clave, el uid del usuario.

Y tu reglas de seguridad son incorrectas. Cualquier usuario puede escribir en el nodo perfiles y no unicamente en su nodo (te falta un nivel más de profundidad en el arbol para escribir).

Pasando en limpio:

**Estructura firebase**

```
 {
  "perfiles" : {
    "zxwDkderfasdl2" : {  //corresponde al id del usuario y no una clave aleatoria
      "apellidos" : "Jaramillo",
      "cedula" : "0103780835",
      "correo" : "info@maquinas.com",
      "direccion" : "Salvador Allende",
      "nacimiento" : "5/3/1983",
      "nombres" : "Andres",
      "whatsapp" : "0984228708"
    }
  }
}
```

**reglas firebase**

```
{
 "rules": {
    "perfiles": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

fijate en las reglas que hay un nivel mas "$uid" para indicar que dentro del nodo "perfiles" es como una lista de entradas.
Ahora un usuario solo puede leer y escribir dentro de "perfiles/su uid" y no puede borrarte todas las entradas con un simple setValue al nivel de "perfiles/" ya que no tendrá acceso.

**por ultimo, para obtener los datos desde Android**

```
baseDatos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
perfilesReferencia = baseDatos.getReference("perfiles");
vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);

// se obtiene al usuario logueado
usuarioLogueado = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = usuarioLogueado.getUid() //no me acuerdo precisamente el nombre del método
Query consulta = perfilesReferencia.child(uid);
consulta.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot ds) {

        Perfil perfilEncontrado = ds.getValue(Perfil.class);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),perfilEncontrado.getCorreo(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        cedulaET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getCedula());
        nombresET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getNombres());
        apellidosET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getApellidos());
        nacimientoET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getNacimiento());
        whatsappET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getWhatsapp());
        direccionET.setText(perfilEncontrado.getDireccion());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No se ha encontrado el perfil",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Ahora no es necesario ordenar por el email ni utilizar "equalTo" solo necesitas obtener el perfil que corresponde al uid del usuario logueado.
Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Gracias Franco por tu respuesta, he hecho los cambios sugeridos, me fue bien con casi todo, se registran con el uid en lugar de con la clave aleatoria y la consulta se hace en base al uid del usuario logueado, pero la aplicación se detiene el momento que se intenta hacer la recuperación de los datos, a lo mejor hay algo más en el código que debas ver.

Comment: @AndrésJaraAvila en la linea FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); chequeas que realmente haya un usuario logueado? sino te va a devolver null. Sino es ese el error, puedes subir el error que te muestra el logcat? También puedes poner un breakpoint dentro de "onDataChange" y ver en el watch si ds.getValue() contiene es null o contiene los datos del usuario. Avísame del error y lo solucionamos!

Comment: Franco, acabo de mirar en el logcat y lo que indica es que faltaba el constructor non-arguments en la clase Perfil, he colocado el constructor y pues eso fue, las cosas que pasan cuando se bloquea y pasa por alto algunas cosas. El codigo estuvo funcional siempre, fue el constructor, pero bueno gané con las reglas y las optimizaciones sugeridas. Gracias hermano, me gustaría poder molestarte si por allí me vuelvo a atascar en algo, claro si se puede.

Comment: @AndrésJaraAvila genial! siempre que te trabes ayúdate con el logcat. Te quería hacer una aclaración más: el evento ValueEventListener va a llamar a OnDataChange aunque no haya encontrado un resultado. Es decir, si escribes "perfiles/algoQueNoExiste" no va a ir a DatabaseError sino que va a devolver un DataSnapshot que no existe. Por lo tanto, puedes chequear lo siguiente antes de tu código: if(ds.exists())... Te aviso esto porque tu menaje en onCancelled es confuso. De todas formas, con las reglas que tenes ahora si quieres buscar un path que no corresponda al uid dará permission denied.

Comment: Y no hay problema, si te trabas te intento ayudar. Intenta buscar primero en Internet y sino puedes lo vemos! Edita tu pregunta para explicar la solución que encontraste y si puedes decir que mi respuesta te fue de utilidad te lo agradezco :) (no la solución porque no lo fue)

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo Franco, lección aprendida y claro que me ha servido tu ayuda y con respecto a lo que me mencionas del mensaje aquel, pues me di cuenta también y lo he cambiado.

Comment: @AndrésJaraAvila lo que quise decir es si puedes votar mi respuesta como correcta así me otorgas reputación que andaría necesitando para llegar a 50 y poder dejar comentarios ^^. Te mando un abrazo!